# ListView contents in Android navigation drawer not lined up

Tags: android, listview

I followed up the [android docs](https://developer.android.com/intl/ko/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) to build a navigation drawer on my app main activity. But the contents are in a string array in my main activity java code. The listview elements are not lined up.[image]

How do I make them lined up to the left so they all are aligned equal distance from the left side of the screen? I also want this behavior in portrait and layout modes. 
This is my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/adla"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/acgetd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <requestFocus />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bgetd"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/skimmy"
                android:text="@string/bgetd" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/brejec"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/skimmy"
                android:text="@string/reject" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/MList"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111">
    </ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link you shared, there is a layout `R.layout.drawer_list_item`. there is an XML layout called `drawer_list_item.xml`. this is the file responsible for all the item in the listView. 
check for `gravity` in the XML and remove it or set the property to `alignParentLeft`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are using android:gravity="center" instead of     android:gravity="center_vertical" in the TextView for the List.

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT be creating this yourself, and instead should be using the AppCompat provided NavigationLayout for this.

This is designed to set this all up for you using just menu.xml files, and using this control will ensure your drawer matches the guidelines exactly.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your Text of ListView is align to the center,

```
android:layout_gravity="center
```

change that to right or left according to your requirement
which may help